# Is there an interchange fee for ATM withdraws? How does that compare to standrad Credit Card purchases

Tags: fees, debit-card, atm

First, please note that I am not asking about how this impacts my personal finances.

I would like to know the difference between fees going to VISA/MC and banks when using a debit card for ATM withdraws VERSUS fees when making a direct debit card purchase.

Put another way: Am I preventing money from going into the hands of VISA (and my bank) if I do an ATM withdraw and spend that cash VERSUS not using an ATM and purchasing with my debit card?

Comment: (my bank does not charge me for any ATM withdraws)

Comment: In what country?

Comment: I'm in the USA now. So USA banks, but I suppose I'm also interested in if the equation changes if I use my same card abroad (there's no foreign transaction/exchange fee).